# Kill a hung child process

Tags: perl, perl-module

My Perl script runs an external program (which takes a single command-line parameter) and processes its output. Originally, I was doing this:

```
my @result = `prog arg`;
```

However, turns out that the program is buggy and hangs unpredictably in rare cases. How can I kill the program if it hasn't exited after a certain amount of time? The script has to work both in Windows and in Linux, and it is my understanding that alarms and forks don't work well (or at all) in Windows.

I found a module called [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-Run/lib/IPC/Run.pm) but I can't figure out how to use it properly from its documentation. :-( I tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);
my $in;
my $out;
my $err;
my @result;
my @cmd = qw(prog arg);
run \@cmd, \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout (10) or die "@cmd: $?";
push @result, $_ while (<$out>);
close $out;
print @result;
```

As a test, I created a program that just sleeps 60 seconds, prints a string to `stdout` and exits. When I try to run it with the above code, it hangs for 60 seconds (instead of for 10 seconds, as specified in the timeout) and aborts with a bizarre error:

```
IPC::Run: timeout on timer #1 at C:/Bin/Unix/Perl/site/lib/IPC/Run.pm line 2956
```

Then I found another module, [Proc::Reliable](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Proc-Reliable/Reliable.pm). From the description, it seems to do precisely what I want. Except that it doesn't work! I tried this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Reliable;

my $proc = Proc::Reliable->new ();
$proc->maxtime (10);
my $out = $proc->run ("prog arg");
print "$out\n";
```

It indeed aborts the child process after 10 seconds. So far, so good. But then I modified the external program and made it sleep for only 5 seconds. This means that the program should finish before the 10-second timeout specified in the above code and its `stdout` output should be captured into the variable `$out`. But it isn't! The above script doesn't output anything.

Any ideas how to do it properly? (Fixing the buggy external program is not an option.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing the output from stderr, status and msg from the Reliable object?

Comment: What happens when you set debug? `Proc::Reliable::debug($level);`

Comment: If I do `Proc::Reliable::debug (1);`, the script just outputs `Proc::Reliable> ATTEMPT 0: 'prog arg'` and nothing else. No output from `$out`. (Of course, if I run the program `prog arg` manually, I _do_ get output.)

Answer (score 3):

Try the poor man's alarm

```
my $pid;
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    $pid = system 1, "prog arg";    # Win32 only, run proc in background
} else {
    $pid = fork();
    if (defined($pid) && $pid == 0) {
        exec("proc arg");
    }
}

my $poor_mans_alarm = "sleep 1,kill(0,$pid)||exit for 1..$TIMEOUT;kill -9,$pid";
system($^X, "-e", $poor_mans_alarm);
```

The poor man's alarm runs in a separate process. Every second, it checks whether the process with identifier $pid is still alive. If the process isn't alive, the alarm process exits. If the process is still alive after $time seconds, it sends a kill signal to the process (I used 9 to make it untrappable and -9 to take out the whole subprocess tree, your needs may vary. `kill 9,...` is also portable).

**Edit:** How do you capture the output of the process with the poor man's alarm?
Not with backticks -- then you can't get the process id and you may lose the intermediate output if the process times out and gets killed. The alternatives are

1) send output to a file, read the file when the process is done

```
$pid = system 1, "proc arg > some_file";
... start poor man's alarm, wait for program to finish ...
open my $fh, '<', 'some_file';
my @process_output = <$fh>;
...
```

2) use Perl's `open` to start the process

```
$pid = open my $proc, '-|', 'proc arg';
if (fork() == 0) {
    # run poor man's alarm in a background process
    exec($^X, '-e', "sleep 1,kill 0,$pid||exit ...");
}
my @process_output = ();
while (<$proc>) {
   push @process_output, $_;
}
```

The `while` loop will end when the process ends, either naturally or unnaturally.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what your code is doing, but once I replace `$TIMEOUT` with a proper value, it mostly works - in the sense that it does terminate the child process after the specified number of seconds and lets it finish running, if it terminates faster than that. However, how do I gather the output from the child process? Unlike the backticks, `system()` doesn't allow me to read the standard output of the program it runs. Something with pipes, perhaps?

Comment: I would prefer not to use temporary files explicitly, so solution 1) is out. Solution 2) is what I was looking for when I asked if it could be done with pipes. It _almost_ does what I need. Its only problem is that it always takes the specified timeout time to run - even if the child process terminates faster than that. At least it is so on Windows; I can't test it on Linux right now.

Comment: Solution 2) works properly on Linux - it terminates either after the timeout, or after the child terminates, whichever comes first. However, I still need a solution that would work correctly on Windows too; currently your solution always takes the specified timeout time to run there, as mentioned above. On a side note, the author of `Proc::Reliable` confirmed that it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work on Windows is because there forks and, apparently, pipes are implemented as threads; not as separate processes. A thread remains "active" (even after exiting) as long as its parent hasn't terminated, so your code `kill 0,$pid` always returns 1. I figured out how to launch a true process using `Win32::Process` (and either terminate it after a specified timeout or let it finish if it does that before the timeout expires) but now I don't know how to capture its `stdout`. :headbang:

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could do. Any ideas on how to avoid the use of a temporary file on Windows would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Temp;
use Win32::Process qw(STILL_ACTIVE NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS);

my $pid;
my $timeout = 10;
my $prog = "prog arg";
my @output;

if ($^O eq "MSWin32")
{
    my $exitcode;
    my $fh = File::Temp->new ();
    my $output_file = $fh->filename;
    close ($fh);
    open (OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT");
    open (STDOUT, ">$output_file" ) || die ("Unable to redirect STDOUT to $output_file.\n");
    Win32::Process::Create ($pid, $^X, $prog, 1, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, '.') or die Win32::FormatMessage (Win32::GetLastError ());
    for (1 .. $timeout)
    {
        $pid->GetExitCode ($exitcode);
        last if ($exitcode != STILL_ACTIVE);
        sleep 1;
    }
    $pid->GetExitCode ($exitcode);
    $pid->Kill (0) or die "Cannot kill '$pid'" if ($exitcode == STILL_ACTIVE);
    close (STDOUT);
    open (STDOUT, ">&OLDOUT");
    close (OLDOUT);
    open (FILE, "<$output_file");
    push @output, $_ while (<FILE>);
    close (FILE);
}
else
{
    $pid = open my $proc, "-|", $prog;
    exec ($^X, "-e", "sleep 1, kill (0, $pid) || exit for 1..$timeout; kill -9, $pid") unless (fork ());
    push @output, $_ while (<$proc>);
    close ($proc);
}
print "Output:\n";
print @output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use alarm system call as in perldoc -f alarm.