# Make timeout work for LWP::UserAgent HTTPS

Tags: perl, ssl, timeout, lwp, lwp-useragent

## Solution

As reported by @limulus in the answer I accepted, this was a bug in `Net::HTTPS` version 6.00. Always be wary of fresh .0 releases. Here's the relevant diff between the buggy and fixed version of that module:

```
D:\Opt\Perl512.32 :: diff lib\Net\HTTPS.pm site\lib\Net\HTTPS.pm
6c6
< $VERSION = "6.00";
---
> $VERSION = "6.02";
75,78c75,80
< # The underlying SSLeay classes fails to work if the socket is
< # placed in non-blocking mode.  This override of the blocking
< # method makes sure it stays the way it was created.
< sub blocking { }  # noop
---
> if ($SSL_SOCKET_CLASS eq "Net::SSL") {
>     # The underlying SSLeay classes fails to work if the socket is
>     # placed in non-blocking mode.  This override of the blocking
>     # method makes sure it stays the way it was created.
>     *blocking = sub { };
> }
```

## Original question

Relevance: It is annoying to see your HTTPS client block indefinitely because the connection endpoint is unreliable.

This experiment is easy to set up and replay at home. You just need two things, a tarpit to trap an incoming client, and a Perl script. The tarpit can be set up using `netcat`:

```
nc -k -l localhost 9999 # on Linux, for multiple requests
nc -l -p 9999 localhost # on Cygwin, for one request only
```

Then, point the script to this tarpit:

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

print 'LWP::UserAgent::VERSION  ', $LWP::UserAgent::VERSION, "\n";
print 'IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION ', $IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION, "\n";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 5, keep_alive => 1 );
$ua->ssl_opts( timeout => 5, Timeout => 5 ); # Yes - see note below!
my $rsp = $ua->request( GET 'https://localhost:9999' );
if ( $rsp->is_success ) {
  print $rsp->as_string;
} else {
  die $rsp->status_line;
}
```

What is this going to do? Well, connect to the port opened by NetCat, and then ... hang. Indefinitely. At least in terms of developer time. I mean it might time out after ten minutes or two hours, but I haven't checked; the specified timeout doesn't take effect, not on Linux, and not on Windows (Win32, haven't checked Cygwin).

Versions used:

```
LWP::UserAgent::VERSION  6.02
IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION 1.44
# on Linux

LWP::UserAgent::VERSION  6.02
IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION 1.44
# on Win32
```

Now for the `timeout` and `Timeout` parameters. The former is the name of the parameter for [LWP::UA](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent), the latter is the name for [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL), used via [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps). (Incidentally, why is metacpan HTTPS? Well, at least it's not a tarpit.) I am somehow hoping to have these parameters passed along :)

Just so you know, `keep_alive` doesn't have anything to do with the timeout not working, I verified that empirically. :)

Anyway, before digging deeper, does anyone know what's going on here and how to make the timeout work with HTTPS? Hard to believe I'm the first person running into this.

Comment: Works for me. Linux/LWP 6.04/IO-S-SSL 1.56

Comment: Thanks, @daxim. On Linux/64 (CentOS release 5.7), I upgraded to those versions. Also upgraded to `Net::SSLeay::VERSION 1.42`. Still blocking. As normal user and as `root`. - Okay, that was ActivePerl (v5.12.4) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi. Installed a couple of modules for the system perl and retried: success! The system perl is v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi; the module versions are the same. Might be a problem pertaining to the perl built. Might. I really don't know. What would be the place to ask about low-level stuff like this?

Comment: I don't know, try [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org) first, knowledgable people hang there. If unsuccessful, ask in [#perl-help](http://irc.perl.org) and the [beginners list](http://lists.perl.org/list/beginners.html) and you will be forwarded to the appropriate place.

Comment: [Asked on Perlmonks.](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=956556)

Comment: metacpan allows you to log in and such. To secure the session, https is required. Having both http for not logged in users and https caused to much headache :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of the `Net::HTTPS` module overriding the `blocking` method of `IO::Socket` with a noop. Upgrading to the [latest `Net::HTTP` package](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Net-HTTP-6.03/) should fix this.

Answer (score 3):

The `timeout` (and `Timeout`) options apply only to the connection -- how many seconds will `LWP::UserAgent` wait while connecting -- they are not for setting a timeout on the whole transaction.

You'll want to use Perl's `alarm` with a `$SIG{ALRM}` handler to timeout the whole transaction. See [`perldoc -f alarm`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#alarm) or [`perlipc`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlipc#Signals).

```
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "SSL timeout\n" };
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 5, keep_alive => 1 );
$ua->ssl_opts( timeout => 5, Timeout => 5 );

eval {
    alarm(10);
    my $rsp = $ua->request( GET 'https://localhost:9999' );
    if ( $rsp->is_success ) {
      print $rsp->as_string;
    } else {
      die $rsp->status_line;
    }
 };
 alarm(0);
 if ($@) {
     if ($@ =~ /SSL timeout/) {
         warn "request timed out";
     } else {
         die "error in request: $@";
     }
 }
```

(tested on Linux. [Alarms can be a bit more cantankerous in Windows/Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397937/))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If what you say is true, how do you explain that the timeout *does work* for plain HTTP? Go ahead and try it, just delete the "s" from "https" and you'll see a nice `500 read timeout`. At least I do, on Win32 and Cygwin, and on Linux, too, of course. - As for `alarm`, I ruled it out as non-portable, and while your solution works on Linux as expected, it hangs indefinitely on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[I asked this question on PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=956556), and [received an answer](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=959915) to the effect that:

> The underlying IO::Socket::INET does not support non-blocking sockets
>   on Win32, thus non-blocking IO::Socket::SSL is not supported on Win32,
>   which means also, that timeouts don't work (because they are based on
>   non-blocking). See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=378675

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.60/README.Win32

The PerlMonks post pointed to is from 2004. Not sure the information still applies; after all, I've seen the timeout *does work* on Windows, just not via SSL.